# Groups between $\operatorname{GL}_n (R)$ and $\operatorname{SL}_n(R)$?

Tags: ring-theory, determinant, linear-groups, general-linear-group

It occurs to me that $R^\times$ (the group of units of a *commutative* ring) may have a subgroup, say $S \leqslant R^\times$.

It seems that we could then define the group
$$
\operatorname{GL}_n(R; S) = \{A \in\operatorname{GL}_n(R) : \det A \in S\}
$$
Does this group make sense? Is something like this studied? Is there anything interesting about $GL_n(R; S)$? The only thing I can think of is that we of course have:
$$
\operatorname{SL}_n(R) \leqslant\operatorname{GL}_n(R; S) \leqslant \operatorname{GL}_n(R)
$$

### Some notes

- As discussed in the comments of the accepted answer, the subgroups of $\operatorname{GL}_n(R)$ containing $\operatorname{SL}_n(R)$ are precisely the $\operatorname{GL}_n(R; S)$.
- For all $n \geq 2$, there are subgroups of $\operatorname{GL}_n(R)$ which neither contain nor are contained by $\operatorname{SL}_n(R)$. An example is
  $$
  \left\{\begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\0 & \mathbb{I}_{n-1} \end{pmatrix} : a \in R^\times \right\} \leqslant\operatorname{GL}_n(R)
  $$

Comment: @DietrichBurde That doesn't seem true to me. For instance, as stated, $SL_n(R)\leq GL_n(R;S)$. How is $SL_n(R)$ a subgroup of $GL_n(R')$?

Comment: Here are two examples of this I have come across "in nature", although neither is particularly earth shattering:  $GL_n(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R}^+)$ is the group of orientation preserving linear transformations, and $GL_n(\mathbb{C}, \{ \pm 1 \})$ is the Zariski closure of $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ in $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: Or if say $\mathcal{O}$ is a number ring and $I \subset \mathcal{O}$ is an ideal, then the image of natural map $GL_n(\mathcal{O}) \to GL_n(\mathcal{O}/I)$ will be of the form  $GL_n(\mathcal{O}/I, U)$ where $U \subset \mathcal{O}/I$ is the image of the units in $\mathcal{O}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Lemma:** If $f:\ A\ \longrightarrow\ B$ is a group homomorphism, then for every subgroup $B'\subseteq B$ the subset $A':=f^{-1}(B')$ is a subgroup of $A'$ containing $\ker f$.  (This is an easy exercise in group theory.)

In particular, the determinant map on $\operatorname{GL}_n(R)$ is a group homomorphism
$$\det:\ \operatorname{GL}_n(R)\ \longrightarrow\ R^{\times},$$
with kernel $\operatorname{SL}_n(R)$. So every subgroup of $S\subset R^{\times}$ defines a subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_n(R)$ containing $\operatorname{SL}_n(R)$ by taking the inverse image under the determinant map:
$$\det{}^{-1}(S)=\{A\in\operatorname{GL}_n(R):\ \det A\in S\}.$$
These are indeed precisely the subgroups you describe. There may of course be more subgroups.

Comment: Is there an easy example of a subgroup of $GL_n(R)$ that doesn't arise as $GL_n(R; S)$ for some $S$? I suppose the Heisenberg group is an example. Any significance to whether or not a subgroup of $GL_n(R)$ arises this way?

Comment: @CharlesHudgins The subgroups that arise this way are exactly the subgroups containing $SL_n (R)$. You've already shown that every subgroup arising this way contains $SL_n (R)$; for the other way around, show that if $SL_n (R)\le H\le GL_n (R)$ and $A\in H$ then every matrix in $GL_n (R)$ with the same determinant as $A$ is also in $H$, then the $S$ you want is exactly $\det[H] = \{\det(A)\mid A\in H\}$. Two easy examples of subgroups of $GL_n (R)$ that don't contain $SL_n (R)$ are the subgroup of invertible diagonal matrices and the subgroup of invertible upper-triangular matrices.

Comment: Any hints for how to show that if $A \in H$ and $\det A = \det B$ then $B \in H$?

Comment: @CharlesHudgins What is $\det(A^{-1} B)$?

Comment: I see. Is the idea that $A^{-1} B \in SL_n(R) \leqslant H$ so $B = A(A^{-1} B) \in H$? By the way, this is exactly the sort of answer I was looking for. Thank you.